# Random.randint and finding a number between two integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a turn based game in Python. At one point, I need to generate a random number out of a hundred and see if it is in-between two numbers. It needs to be in the if statement.

```
elif random.randint(0,100) #is equal a number between 20 and 60
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: elif 20 < random.randint(0, 100) < 60:

Answer (score 3):

`if low < random.randint(0,100) < high` does the job well, unless you want to store the random value in a variable

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
elif random.randint(0,100) in range(20, 61)
```

Comment: True. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: Actually, from https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges: "Changed in version 3.2: Implement the Sequence ABC. Support slicing and negative indices. Test int objects for membership in constant time instead of iterating through all items.". So it's good.

Comment: @CătălinMatei depends on the Python version... so you may want to at least mention that your solution is inefficient on Python < 3.2 ;)

Comment: I didn't know until now, but thanks to you it's all good now :}.